# Screen recording crashes when web browser is refreshed

Tags: screen-recording, camtasia

So I am trying to record my screen for a demo video. I am using Camtasia 2019 but I am also trying out Bandicam. I have it setup to record a web application on my google chrome web browser but for some reason when the web browser is refreshed it stops the recording. Both camtasia and bandicam have this issue so I am not sure what is causing that, and I am wondering if anybody else has ran into the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well if anybody wants an answer to this, the issue was with the cpu of my virtual machine. I did not have enough resources allocated to handle the page refresh while recording. If you watch the performance of your machine while refreshing your web browser you will see it shoot the cpu up to the top of the processing power so when it would do that the video would stop recording. The fix was to allocate more resources to the virtual machine.